# Business Verification for chatbot

Tags: chatbot, messenger

I created a chatbot  using Dialogflow, I submitted it for review and the problem is: I dont have a business (just a page in facebook) for the "Business Verification" so no:

> - Business license (preferred)
> - Certificate of formation
> - Articles of incorporation document
> - Business utility or phone bill

Please, what is the solution for my case ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As facebook is fighting to gain their image back after being involved in some major data breaches recently, they are asking Chatbot developers to connect their Bots to real businesses.

The business verification process will take time from weeks to months, requiring appropriated documents proving the page business is real!

I see, therefore, there's no chance to publish your bot now, or even in the future, without having any serious business for the page!

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, for people like you and me they are currently rolling out "[Individual Verification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#individual-verification)":

> If you submit your app for review and you are asked to complete business verification, but you don't own or run a business, you may be given the option to complete individual verification instead. By completing individual verification, you can gain full or limited access to the products listed below. [...]

Comment: Thanks, but they only sent me a link for Business Verification. How can I request an Individual Verification?

Comment: Same to me.I have the same issue. Did you revolve it?